# HashMap dont stay stable in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, hashmap

Hi I am trying to save a object in HashMap if it is not exist than if it is exsit I want to control its value with new data. If data change than I want to do sth. else. But whenever I tried to compare new data and hash value I saw they are same on every time . How can I handle with this issue. There is code:

```
BluetoothLeDevice deviceLe;
private Map<String, byte[]> mMacMap;
byte [] integer0 =new byte[4];
byte[] tempInteger0=new byte[4];

public void addSensor(String macId, BluetoothLeDevice deviceLe) {
        byte [] addSensorrecord=deviceLe.getScanRecord();
        int j=0;
        for(int i=15;i<19;i++)
        {
            integer0 [j]=addSensorrecord[i];
            j++;
        }
        if (mMacMap.containsKey(macId)) {
            tempInteger0 = mMacMap.get(macId);

            if(!integer0 .equals(tempInteger0))
            {
                mMacMap.remove(macId);
                mMacMap.put(macId, integer0 );
                new SendBLEData().execute(deviceLe);
            }

        } else {
            final byte [] LocalInteger0=new byte[4];
            int t=0;
            for(int i=15;i<19;i++)
            {
                LocalInteger0[t]=addSensorrecord[i];
                t++;
            }
            mMacMap.put(macId, LocalInteger0);
            new SendBLEData().execute(deviceLe);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hint: read java coding style guides. Variable names start lowerCase. And you should use names that tell something about the intention of the variable; so ... what the heck is an Integer0 Array about? You see, alone the way you are writing code is just creating confusion all over the place.

Comment: Then: in order to understand your code, we would need to see the declarations of the variables you are using.

Comment: declerations added

Comment: tempInteger0 still missing. And for the record: turn to the help center to understand how to write up "code not working" questions. Hint: not like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few additions to the already posted answers.

The remove below is not necessary, a simple put will replace the old value

```
mMacMap.remove(macId);
mMacMap.put(macId, integer0 );
```

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V))

> If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value
>   is replaced by the specified value. (A map m is said to contain a
>   mapping for a key k if and only if m.containsKey(k) would return
>   true.)

Have you considered making bytes 15-19 into a string and adding them onto the maps key?  This would eliminate the array compare and make the lookups much faster.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing, that your problem is here:

```
!Integer0.equals(tempInteger0))
```

I *think* you want to compare two arrays; and you are surprised to find them to be different ... all the time.

Your problem is: equals() on arrays doesn't do a comparison of the array content. In other words: this call to equals() only gives "true" if the arrays you are comparing ... are **one and the same**, like in:

```
  int a[] = { 1 };
  int b[] = a;
  int c[] = { 1 };
```

Here:

```
 a.equals(b) --> true
```

but

```
 a.equals(c) --> false
```

When comparing array content matters, then you should use ArrayList instead. Because two ArrayList objects are **equal** when they contain exactly the same **equal** elements.

And you see: you are using that equals on arrays to make a decision in your code. So, you either change to ArrayLists; or use Arrays.equals() as user hamsty suggested.

Comment: maybe you are right but when I debug it I can see they are same.

Comment: Then lets rephrase: using arrays for tasks like this is definitely very bad practice; with high potential of causing problems.

Comment: my problem is hashmap updated automatically when scan record changed

Comment: Your hashmap is being updated because you are overwriting integer0 which is a global variable, maybe create a local array. The equals case will always be equal because you are comparing an array to itself. Keep in mind that you are only comparing the array addresses and not their actual content

Comment: fuadj but at first time I call this func I put a local variable LocalInteger0 in else statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
 !Integer0.equals(tempInteger0))
```

is your problem.

Use this to compare the content of arrays:

```
Arrays.equals(Integer0, tempInteger0)
```

Comment: my problem is not equality ny problem is with hashmap. It is updating automatically when scanrecord changed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following sequence of events:

1. `macId` not in `mMacMap`, insert `new byte[4];` into the map
2. `macId` in `mMacMap`, the array created in the previous step never matches `integer0` due to the Array comparison problem mentioned by the other answer, replace `macId` in the map with a reference to `integer0`
3. `macId` in `mMacMap`, since the array is a reference to `integer0`, it will always compare positively and the contents will no longer be updated.
4. Repeat 3.

Basically caused by these two issues:

1. `Array#equals` does not behave intuitively, use the static method `Arrays.equals`
2. Java is heavily reference-based, so if you insert something into a map it will not be copied, but simply a new reference is created; this may bite you if you change a shared object afterwards (like the array).